# Grid Issue By Using <div> and <a>

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have one silly question about Bootstrap Grid System.

Is that okay to use `<a href="#" class="col-lg-4">` instead of `<div class="col-lg-4">`?

Is it because I want create a column-4 grid menu with hyperlink.

Basically, it should look like this which the hyperlink only cover the text not the whole column even if I had styled `width: 100%; height: 100%;` inside the `<a>` tag.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

After I change the code, it should look like

```
<div class="row">
    <a href="#" class="col-lg-4">
        Menu 1
    </a>
</div>
```

Is this a best practice of using Bootstrap?
Or we have to follow the standard which define by Bootstrap?

Comment: Why not use `nav` for your menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do it like this and it will be looking great:
just add a class or style to your a element. 
or add class "btn btn-default btn-block" to use bootstrap button styles

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-4 text-center">
    <a href="#" class=" btn-block">
        Menu 1
    </a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel.

Your solution works in materialize.css also.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I see with that is that the `A` won't have the css property `display: block;` by default so you might run into styling issues. If you fix this issue by adding this property, I can see any problem with that.